# Need a word to generalize weapons, gears and items

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm programming for a video game and have run into naming problems.

There are 3 categories of things the hero can acquire. There are weapons that the hero uses to attack. There are gears, such as accessories and clothes, that increase the hero's stats. There are items, such as potions and books, that the hero can use.

From the code's perspective, weapons, gears and items are quite similar. They all have names, descriptions, pictures and effects. So I'm writing a common class to store the properties of these things. The class is to be called `XXXProperties`, and used by every kind of weapons, gears and items.

Problem is I can't find a good name for this class. The name should be a generalization of all 3 categories. I have thought of calling the third category "consumable" instead of "item", so I can refer to all of weapons, gears and consumables as items. However not all consumables are, well, consumable. As mentioned earlier there are books that do not disappear after use.

So what I need is a word, YYY, that refers to things that can be used, and another word, XXX, that generalizes weapons, gears and YYY, so I can call my class `XXXProperties`. Sample sentence:

> We should make a prefab for every kind of weapon, gear and YYY there is. Each prefab should have the `XXXProperties` component attached and filled out so the UI can find its name and sprites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; naming requests are expressly off-topic on ELU as they lead to answers whose appropriateness is a matter of opinion rather than correct / incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

*Here is a list of words that may suit your need, ordered by relevance*:

- "**Stock**"
- "**Acquirables**"
- "**Attainables**"
- "**Item**"
- "**Consumables**"

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to go with "articles", and keep calling items items. So now weapons, gears and items are all referred to as articles.

You are still welcome to post better answers.

Comment: How about “supplies”?

Answer (score 1):

Please note "gear" in this context is a collective term made up of "pieces of gear" or "items of gear", not "gears", which are things you find in machinery.

Answer (score -2):

- Inventory

  - Gear
  - Weapon
  - Item

Seriously, don't overthink your naming conventions; you only have 3 classes of objects here, so it's not like you're going to get confused over the difference between an Item and a Weapon. "Inventory" and "Item" are acceptably self-documenting, could shorthand "Inventory" as "Inv," etc.  Bonus: less characters to typo, ftw.

- (Inventory.Properties? If you had properties applicable to all inventory objects, this would make potentially make sense)

  - Inventory.Gear

    - Inventory.Gear.Properties
  - Inventory.Weapon

    - Inventory.Weapon.Properties
  - Inventory.Item

    - Inventory.Item.Properties